# Drop Down Navs not working with Bootstrap & Wordpress

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm using bootstrap to create my page templates for a wordpress site but I am having trouble getting my dropdown nav to work when I add a child in the wordpress menu screen.

Here is my header code...

```
  <body id="grad1">
<div class="mynavbar">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-1">
                <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/logo_80px.png" class=" center-block space" alt="Enter OmniMark here"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-0">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-1">
                    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/OMsemicircle.png" class=" center-block space" alt="Enter OmniMark here"/>
                </div>
             </div>
       </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="fontfix">
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="center-block">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse column " id="navbar-collapse-2">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!--<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>-->

            <?php /* Primary navigation */
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu' => 'menu 1',
  'depth' => 0,
  'container' => false,
  'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse column',
  'container_id' => 'navbar-collapse-2',
  'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
  //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
  'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
);
?>



            <!--Used to list nav and exclude pages-->
            <!--<?php wp_list_pages(array('title_li' => '', 'exclude' => '615, 14',)); ?>-->
            <li><a href="" alt="">Store</a></li>
           </ul>

  <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="module top widewrapper center-block">

        <h1><span class="fontgreen">Thin Film</span><span class="fontblue"> Product Markings</span></h1>
        <p class="darktext">The world is full of products and brands whose image gets lost in the white noise of modern society. The Lauterbach Group protects your brand’s unique and inspiring image with film product markings. Thin film product markings provide exceptional decoration options, increased production efficiencies and supply chain savings with an environmental focus.</p>
    <!--<img class="center-block" src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/homepage_800.png" alt="" />-->

    </div>


    <div class="container mainbump">
```

I can also provide the functions code if that will help...

```
<?php 
//trying to register menu
/* Theme setup */
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpt_setup' );
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wpt_setup' ) ):
        function wpt_setup() {  
            register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary navigation', 'wptuts' ) );
        } endif;

// Register custom navigation walker
    require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

//menu registery
function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));


    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'footer',
        'id' => 'footer',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'sidebarmenu',
        'id' => 'sidebarmenu',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));




?>
```

Comment: I think I may have figured it out I added more classes to my 'menu_class'

     'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top'

Answer (score 0):

The 'depth' value in the array is 0, you should change it to 2 or 3 if you want more.

Here's my example for the Wordpress wp_bootstraap_navkwalker() function.

```
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button"  class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div><!--end navbar-header-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse menu-primary" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'              => '',
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                    'depth'             => 3,
                    'container'         => '',
                    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
                ?>

            </div><!--end navbar-colapse-->
        </div><!--end container-->
    </nav>
```

Try that and you should be good.